# Consultas SQL dos nomes dos estados com a respectiva quantidade de cidades

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa noite, estou começando a estudar SQL e estou fazendo pequenas consultas no banco de dados para praticar. Mas cai nessa que pede para exibir os nomes dos estados com a respectiva quantidade de cidades e simplesmente não consigo. Consigo relacionar as cidades com os seus estados mas não consigo deixar apenas o estado com a respectiva quantidade de cidades.

Comment: No site tem busque group by

Answer (score 1):

Boa noite, Vinicius. O ideal seria que você colocasse o esquema da tabela em questão, mas acredito que seja uma tabela 'cidade' com um campo 'estado' dentro dela.

---

Tente isso: 
`SELECT estado, COUNT(nome_cidade) AS 'Quantidade de Cidades' <br>
FROM cidade <br>
GROUP BY estado`

"A cláusula GROUP BY agrupa linhas baseado em semelhanças entre elas". Nesse caso ela está agrupando a quantidade de cidades que compartilham como semelhança o mesmo estado.

Comment: esqueci de dizer as tabelas mas consegui resolver com:                                     select e.nome estados, count(*) quantidade_cidade
from estado e inner join municipio m 
on e.codestado = m.codestado 
group by e.nome
order by quantidade_cidade